# How to remove NaN values in pandas dataframe whose columns are referenced in another dataframe as encoded values indicating missing or unknown values

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, data-science, concatenation

**Dataframe 1**

```
1  C1  C2  C3  .  .  .  C85
2  
3  
4  
.
.
800000  .  .  .  .  .  .
```

Columns with missing values across rows

```
0       32
100     10
200     7
300     7
400     6
1000    5
2000    3
3000    3
9000    3
12000   2
13000   1
15000   1
20000   1
30000   1
40000   1
50000   1
60000   1
```

**Dataframe 2**

```
attribute  missing_or_unknown
C1         [-1,X]
C2         [XX]
.          .
.          .
C85        []
```

Missing values sorted by value_Counts()

```
[-1]        26
[-1,9]      17
[-1,0]      16
[0]         12
[]          10
[-1,0,9]     1
[-1,XX]      1
[-1,X]       1
[XX]         1
```

**Need**
Dataframe 1 is the master table that has many missing or unknown values that needs to be cleaned up.
However that determination needs to happen by referencing dataframe 2 and using those encoded indicators in missing_or_unknown column

**Approach**
To be able to do that, I was trying to concat the 2 dataframes and see if i can add that missing_or_unknown column to dataframe 1 before i could proceed and use replace function to replace those indicators with np.nan

**Question** 
How do i perform concatenation when the 2 dataframes don't have same number of rows? Basically 1st dataframe's columns are rows in 2nd dataframe?

Comment: with what logic do you get `-1` and `X` for row 1? I cant see any similar values in th test df. can you update the test and expected dataframes to e more meaningful?

Comment: Actually, i didnt' derive those values. That was the dataset i was provided (See the different types of encoded values  are [-1,X],[-1,9] etc..but that is not something i am concerned about ).....I need to clean dataframe 1 by determining what values are safe to be deemed missing OR unknown by linking the columns in dataframe 1 to these encoded values, that is why i am looking to have these encoded values concatenated/ merged into dataframe 1 as a new column before doing that determination. Hope this makes sense

Comment: @anky_91 - Once i have that column in dataframe 1 , i was thinking of having an enumerate function to loop through the dataframe and run some conditions to see if missing_or_unknown indicator  - ind is [-1,X] OR [-1,9], then  `data[col].replace(ind, np.nan)`..but i am struggling to get to this point, hence looking for a way where i can do concat/ merge OR anything on the 2 dataframes to have missing_or_unknown column added to dataframe 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you transpose the **Dataframe2** and replace the column headings with the values of 1st row and then **concanate Dataframe1 and Dataframe2**. After this, you can operate on the Row1 of the resultant Dataframe to further replace it with "Nan" values.

Here is a sample of this:

```
import pandas as pd

dummy_data1 = {
        'C1': ['11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20'],
        'C2': ['A', 'E', 'I', 'M', 'Q', 'A', 'E', 'I', 'M', 'Q', ],
        'C3': ['B', 'F', 'J', 'N', 'R', 'B', 'F', 'J', 'N', 'R', ],
        'C4': ['C', 'G', 'K', 'O', 'S', 'C', 'G', 'K', 'O', 'S', ],
        'C5': ['D', 'H', 'L', 'P', 'T', 'D', 'H', 'L', 'P', 'T', ]}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(dummy_data1, columns = ['C1', 'C2', 'C3', 'C4', 'C5'])

dummy_data2 = {
        'attribute': ['C1', 'C2', 'C4', 'C5', 'C3', ],
        'missing_or_unknown': ['X1', 'X2', 'X4', 'X5', 'X3', ]}

df2 = pd.DataFrame(dummy_data2, columns = ['attribute', 'missing_or_unknown'])

df2_transposed = df2.transpose()
print("df2_transposed=\n", df2_transposed)
df2_transposed.columns = df2_transposed.iloc[0]
df2_transposed = df2_transposed.drop(df2_transposed.index[0])
print("df2_transposed with HEADER Replaced=\n", df2_transposed)

df_new = pd.concat([df2_transposed, df1])
print("df_new=\n", df_new)
```

Comment: Thanks @AK.Pandian, this solution helped me understand the approach.. However i just wrote a loop to scan across the 2 dataframes to find if those encoded values in df2 belong to df1, then replace with np.Nan